# Uploading files to remote server

Tags: c#, wpf

I am a  WPF newbie and has little experience with C# thread programming. I am assigned a C# WPF application with multi-threading. The requirements for that application is to upload local big files to a
destination folder named "ABC" that sits directly under the root disk driver (e.g. C:\ABC) on a remote server that runs under 
Windows platform. I do not know the directions to go. Please advise.  Thank you.

Follows are details about the requirements:

1. Because each uploaded file size is big, there needs a separate thread to run the upload file function.
   I plan to use thread programming with async/await and Task object. Any idea?
2. In WPF I do not know which WPF control to use for upload function. Please help.
3. For destination folder "ABC", do I need to set its access permission explicitly?
4. I should use async/await and Task, or BackgroundWorker class?

**Update:**

WPF application not WCF application. Sorry for my typo.

Comment: This is covering a lot! You might be better (and get more detailed answers) if you break this down into three separate questions.

Comment: you have some details I would suggest being a `newbie` as you say.. do a google search on C# and asych await.. or C# and Task with WCF also I would suggest writing the code initially as a `Console` application get the functionality working then port it over to your target framework and build from there..

Comment: The following article seems to provide an overview of your target solution:  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166763/WCF-Streaming-Upload-Download-Files-Over-HTTP

Answer (score 1):

To transfer large files using `WCF` service over `HTTP`, you can use the following types of bindings:

- `wsHttpBinding`
- `basicHttpBinding`

In `wsHttpBinding`, we can set the `TransferMode` attribute as `Buffered`, but there is a disadvantage in using this approach for large files, because it needs to put the entire file in memory before uploading/downloading, A large buffer is required on both the web client and the WCF service host. However, this approach is very useful for transferring small files, securely.

In `basicHTTPBinding` we can use the `TransferMode` attribute as `Streamed` so that the file can be transferred in the form of chunks.

For more information follow this article:
[WCF Streaming: Upload/Download Files Over HTTP](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166763/WCF-Streaming-Upload-Download-Files-Over-HTTP)

and for transfering files over `TCP/IP` read below articls:

[WCF TCP-based File Server](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33825/WCF-TCP-based-File-Server)

[Sending Files using TCP](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32633/Sending-Files-using-TCP)

[Large Message Transfer with WCF-Adapters Part 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/paolos/archive/2010/05/25/large-message-transfer-with-wcf-adapters-part-1.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I made a mistake for original post. The application is C# WPF not WCF.